# Did Shiva's incarnation Lakulisha meet Krishna or other Mahabharata characters?

Tags: shiva, avatars, shiva-purana

In [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/Ixm9) from the Shatarudra Samhita of the Shiva Purana, Shiva tells Brahma about his incarnations (avataras) in the Dwapara Yugas of the various Mahayugas in the Vaivasvata Manvantara (the current Manvantara).  And this is what he says about the Dwapara Yuga of the twenty-eighth Mahayuga (the current Mahayuga):

> In the twenty-eighth aeon of Dvapara, there will be Dvaipayana Vyasa, the son of Parashara ,and the most excellent of Purushas [Vishnu] shall be born as Krishna with his one-sixth part, as the foremost of the sons of Vasudeva.  Then I too shall be born with the body of a Brahmachari and the soul of a Yogi by means of Yogic Maya to the great surprise of the worlds.  On seeing a dead body forsaken in the cremation ground I shall enter into it and make it free from ailments by means of Yogic Maya for the welfare or Brahmins.  Then I will enter the holy divine cavern of Meru along with you and Vishnu.  O Brahma, I shall then be known as Lakulin.

Lakulin, also known as Lakulisha, was a famous Shaivite thinker who introduced the Pashupata vow, an ancient method of propitiating Shiva which among other things involves smearing ash all over your body; Shiva is described as the originator of the Pashupati vow in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b112.htm) and [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c049.htm) of the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata.

Now the text of the Shiva Purana has suffered a lot of corruption, so it's possible that this description of Lakulisha is a later interpolation.  But my question is, assuming the passage is authentic, are there any stories of Lakulisha meeting any prominent Dwapara Yuga figures?  The Dwapara Yuga was the time of Krishna, the Pandavas, the Kauravas, Vyasa, etc.  So did Lakulisha have dealings with any of them?

On a side note, does anyone know what the story is of Lakulisha entering the cavern of Mount Meru along with Brahma and Vishnu?

EDIT: I just noticed that the excerpt from the Shiva Purana I provided says [this](http://gdurl.com/Ixm9):

> Oh great lord, the Vyasas in every recurring Dvapara age are twenty-eight in number.  The Yogeshwara incarnations at the beginning of every recurring Kali Age are also so many.

Since Lakulisha is a Yogeshwara incarnation of Shiva, does that mean that Lakulisha lived in the Kali Yuga and not the Dwapara Yuga?  Then he presumably wouldn't have a chance to meet Krishna or the Pandavas.

Comment: It was mentioned that those Shiva Yogeswara incarnations are born at the end of Dvapara Yuga and continue to live in Kaliyuga teaching their four disciplines and those disciplines teaching Yoga techniques to people of Kaliyuga. This helps people of Kaliyuga to liberate.

Comment: Lakulesha was the biggest devotee of Lord Shiva and he had did tapasya for too many years. After too many years,he was found by some people in a cave. He was about to die in the cave but he was rescue by the people.