# What do we know about the future Mahayugas?

Tags: puranas, scripture, yuga, time

**Background:**

The four Yugas (Satya, Treta, Dwapara, and Kali) together make up one Mahayuga.  1000 Mahayugas make up one Kalpa, which is one day in the life of Brahma.  After the Kalpa is over Brahma goes to sleep, and there's a Pralaya which destroys the three worlds, at the end of which Brahma wakes up and creates the world anew.  But as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6536/36), in addition to being divided into 1000 Mahayugas, a Kalpa is also divided into 14 periods known as Manvantaras, in which a figure known as a Manu rules over humanity. Since there are 14 Manus who rule in a given Kalpa, each Manu rules for about 71 Mahayugas.

Now unless Hinduism Stackexchange manages to survive past the Kali Yuga (!), we are all currently living in the 28th Kali Yuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  There are plenty of scriptures that talk about past, present, and future Manvantaras.  And there are scriptures that talk about the first 28 Mahayugas of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  For instance, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3618/36) the Vishnu Purana lists the Vedavyasas or compilers of the Vedas in the first 28 Dwapara Yugas of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  And the Shiva Purana discusses the various Yogeshwara incarnations Shiva has taken in the first 28 Mahayugas of the Vaivasvata Manvantaras, including Lakulisha whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2481/36).  And there are various references in the Puranas to incarnations of Vishnu in the first 28 Mahayugas, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7192/36).

**But my question is, what do we know about the future Mahayugas of the present Vaivasvata Manvantara?**

I only know about two things that will happen in the 29th Mahayuga (i.e. the next Mahayuga):

1. In the 29th Satya Yuga, Shantanu's brother Devāpi and Rama's descendant Maru will re-establish the lunar and solar dynasties, as described in [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/2/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

   > After the one thousand celestial years of Kali-yuga, the Satya-yuga will manifest again. At that time the minds of all men will become self-effulgent.... Devāpi, the brother of Mahārāja Śāntanu, and Maru, the descendant of Ikṣvāku, both possess great mystic strength and are living even now in the village of Kalāpa.  At the end of the Age of Kali, these two kings, having received instruction directly from the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Vāsudeva, will return to human society and reestablish the eternal religion of man, characterized by the divisions of varṇa and āśrama, just as it was before.
2. As I discuss in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2390/36), in the 29th Dwapara Yuga, Drona's son Ashwatthama will become the next Vedavyasa or compiler of the Vedas.  This is described by Vyasa's father Parashara in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin//vp/vp077.htm) of the Vishnu Purana:

   > In the next Dwápara, Drauńi (the son of Drońa) will be the Vyása, when my son, the Muni Krishńa Dwaipáyana, who is the actual Vyása, shall cease to be (in that character).

---

- **But what else do we know about the 29th Mahayuga?**
- **And are there any scriptures which mention events in later Mahayugas of the Vaivasvata Manvantara?**
- If not, how is it that we have information in Hindu scripture about events in all future Manvantaras of the present Kalpas, but absolutely no information about the 30th and subsequent Mahayugas of the present Manvantara?

Comment: I asked a similar question, about the previous Manvantaras [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9367/what-about-the-technology-of-the-previous-kali-yugas). Maybe you could go through it, and get some ideas (and if possible answer my query)? Because the best way to learn is from past experiences...

Comment: Forget future Mahayugas, We don't have much information about KALI DEMON(very less info is known about him)and why yugas have to be repeated and what happens to kali demon exactly at the end of KaliYuga. Most of the Vaishnava Puranas only highlights those avatars of Vishnu where he killed "Jaya and Vijaya" demons. Vyasa might  intentionally hide information about future Mahayugas and Kali Demon.

Comment: @AnilKumar First of all, I don't know for sure if what happens to the demon Kali is discussed or not, but either way that's a pretty minor topic; the important point is that the Yugas repeat, not which specific figure is the deity related to the Yuga.  And the Puranas speak about way more incarnations than the four that fought incarnations of Jaya and Vijaya.  We have plenty of information about incarnations that Vishnu has taken in the past Mahayugas of this Manvantara, and information about incarnations of Vishnu in future Manvantaras. So I don't see why Vyasa would conceal future Mahayugas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Are there any references to Yugas in Vedas? Why didn't sages ask Vyasa " Why Yugas are repeating?", when they asked him some petty questions.

Comment: One of the event thats going to happen is that Bali will become next Indra.

Comment: @Aby That's an event that will happen in a future Manvantara.  My question is about events that will happen in future Mahayugas of the present Manvantara.

Comment: Friends, before going into future yugas, first try to see/learn what has happened during Krita yuga, when and how it ended, Treta Yuga(before Rama's advent), again in Dwapara yuga before Shri Krishna as the span of these earlier 3 yugas were very vast compared to present Kali Yuga. I don't think any material in this regard is readily available even if available, will not be made known to commeners like you and me. How the earth before the continental shift and the advancement of science, the different religions present at that time etc. Probably no present day religion has got that kind of inf

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan We know names of future Saptarshis of next manvantara i.e, Saavarna Manvnatara. [Parasurama is one of them](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10672/3500).

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, we have lots of information about future Manvantaras.  But my question is about information about future Mahayugas in the presen Manvantara.

Comment: @user4793, there is info about a king dividing the earth into 7 dveepas for his sons. that could be what scientists refer to as the 'pangea' before the continents split, and they fit like puzzles pieces even today.

Comment: The vedas do not mention yugas. Only the puranas mention the yugas. "Scripture" is a vague term. You know better.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda First of all, there are mentions of Yugas in some Upanishads.  Second of all, I don't think Hindu scripture is an imprecise term at all.  The Purva Mimamsa Sutras lay out the categories of scripture very clearly.  In any case, the Puranas give information on past Manvantaras of the present Kalpa, future Manvantaras of the present Kalpa, and past Mahayugas of the present Manvantara.  So we may also have information on future Mahayugas of the present Manvantara.  That's what my question is about.

Comment: there might be mention of yugas in some minor late upanishads, but there is no mention in the major upanishads which form part of the vedas or the vedas.

Comment: Future Buddha also decided for Satyuga, Maitreya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitreya to be born in Varanasi. Pali sources say that beings in Maitreya's time will be much bigger than during the time of Sakyamuni. In one prophecy his disciples are contemptuous of Mahakasyapa, whose head is no larger than an insect to them. Buddhas robe barely covers two fingers making them wonder how tiny Buddha was. Mahākāśyapa is said to be small enough in comparison to cremate in the palm of Maitreya's hand.

Comment: Maitreya Buddha will be born in a time when humans will live to an age of eighty thousand years, in the city of Ketumatī (present Varanasi), whose king will be the Cakkavattī Sankha.

Comment: THere is no Devapi.

Comment: What nonsense, only Bhishma, Kripacharya, Vyasa and Ashwathama from Mahabharata are there

Answer (score 5):

Future events of mahayugas

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm

Savarni Manvantara

> In the period in which Sávarńi shall be the Manu, the classes of the gods will be Sutapas, Amitábhas, and Mukhyas; twenty-one of each. **The seven Rishis will be Díptimat, Gálava, Ráma, Kripa, Drauńi; my son Vyása will be the sixth, and the seventh will be Rishyasringa.** The Indra will be Bali, the sinless son of Virochana, who through the favour of Vishńu is actually sovereign of part of Pátála. The royal progeny of Sávarńi will be Virajas, Arvarívas, Nirmoha, and others.

---

Daksha savarni manvantara

> The ninth Manu will be Daksha-sávarńi 8. The Páras, Maríchigarbhas, and Sudharmas will be the three classes of divinities, each consisting of twelve; their powerful chief will be the Indra Adbhuta. Savana, Dyutimat, Bhavya, Vasu, Medhatithi, Jyotishmán, and Satya will be the seven Rishis. Dhritaketu, Driptiketu, Panchahasta, Mahámáyá, Prithuśrava, and others, will be the sons of the Manu.

---

Brahma-savarni manvantara

> In the tenth Manwantara the Manu will be Brahmá-sávarńi: the gods will be the Sudhámas, Viruddhas, and Śatasankhyas: the Indra will be the mighty Śánti: the Rishis will be Havishmán, Sukriti, Satya, Apámmúrtti, Nábhága, Apratimaujas, and Satyaketu: and the ten sons of the Manu will be Sukshetra, Uttarnaujas, Harisheńa, and others.

---

Dharma-sávarńi manvantara

> In the eleventh Manwantara the Manu will be Dharma-sávarńi: the principal classes of gods will be the Vihangamas, Kámagamas, and Nirmánaratis, each thirty in number 9; of whom Vrisha will be the Indra: the Rishis will be Niśchara, Agnitejas, Vapushmán, Vishńu, Áruni, Havishmán, and Anagha: the kings of the earth, and sons of the Manu, will be Savarga, Sarvadharma, Deváníka, and others.

---

12th manvantara

> In the twelfth Manwantara the son of Rudra, Sávarńi, will be the Manu: Ritudhámá will be the Indra: and the Haritas, Lohitas, Sumanasas, and Sukarmas will be the classes of gods, each comprising fifteen.

---

13th manvantara

> In the thirteenth Manwantara the Manu will be Rauchya 10: the classes of gods, thirty-three in each, will be the Sudhámans, Sudharmans, and Sukarmans; their Indra will be Divaspati: the Rishis will be Nirmoha, Tatwadersín, Nishprakampa, Nirutsuka, Dhritimat, Avyaya, and Sutapas: and Chitrasena, Vichitra, and others, will be the kings.

---

14th manvantara

> In the fourteenth Manwantara, Bhautya will be the Manu 11; Suchi, the Indra: the five classes of gods will be the Chákshushas, the Pavitras, Kanisht́has, Bhrájiras, and Vávriddhas: the seven Rishis will be Agnibáhu, Śuchi, Śukra, Magadhá, Gridhra, Yukta, and Ajita: and the sons of the Manu will be Uru, Gabhíra, Bradhna, and others, who will be kings, and will rule over the earth 12.

---

What happens after these manvantaras are over?

> An entire Kalpa, oh Brahman, is said to comprise a thousand ages, or fourteen Manwantaras 13; and it is succeeded by a night of similar duration; during which, he who wears the form of Brahmá, Janárddana, the substance of all things, the lord of all, and creator of all, involved in his own illusions, and having swallowed up the three spheres, sleeps upon the serpent Śesha, amidst the ocean 14. Being after that awake, he, who is the universal soul, again creates all things as they were before, in combination with the property of foulness (or activity): and in a portion of his essence, associated with the property of goodness, he, as the Manus, the kings, the gods, and their Indras, as well as the seven Rishis, is the preserver of the world.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a lot. However in addition to what you mentioned. [Brahmanda Purana](https://archive.org/stream/dli.bengal.10689.12922/10689.12922_djvu.txt) (which I am reading currently) 74 chapter says

> **251-253.** In the twenty-fourth Catur-Tuga (set of four
> Yugas) these will be the persons responsible for the function¬
> ing of Ksatriya race. **A son named Suvarcas will be born to
> Iksvaku in the twentyninth Yuga**. He will be the founder
> in the race. Paula shall be the first person in the Aila dynasty
> of Devapi. These two will be the persons who set the
> Ksatriya race function in the set of four Yugas. The same
> principle regarding the perpetuation of the line should be
> understood everywhere. When the Kali Yuga lapses, they
> will be born in the Kfta Yuga.

Comment: It is so exciting to know about 29th Mahayuga. Is there anything else you know about the 29th Mahayuga?

Answer (score -1):

It is like the major yuga are like a wheel one after the other they come after every kal yug is a sat yuga where everyone is happy then little by little corruption starts stemming and then starts the cycle of the four yuga with the final ending with the start of another sat yug,as told in bhagwat gita the kali demon is basically the demon inside and not the one outside us , we have to gain victory over it.

This is because as lord Krishna tells in bhagwat gita "I(GOD) am persent in any and every being alive or dead and it is I who would end whats evil and I who would start whats good"

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. Please cite some sources to support your answer

Comment: Thank you , the basic source my answer comes from is bhagwat gita and unfortunately the shloka number is unknown to me but the person who taught me was very well reading it and teaching me