# Will Parashurama reappear in Kaliyuga?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, avatars, parashurama, kali-yuga

According to Hindu mythology, Parashurama is the sixth avatar of Vishnu. He appeared during the last Treta and Dwapara Yugas, he also played important role in the Ramayana and Mahabharata.

Are there any chances of Parashurama reappearing in Kaliyuga?

Comment: No Parashurama will not reappear in Kaliyuga, Rather now only Kalki avatar will come as mentioned in the Shri Mad Bhagavatham Purana.

Comment: According to Hindu mythology, Parashurama will appear and give Lord Kalki teachings of Vedas. He will be the teacher of Lord Kalki who will be incarnation of Lord Vishnu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. According to [Kalki Purana](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByTCDrDij9HBWVA4VHYzY2g4elU/edit?pref=2&pli=1), **Parasurama will teach Vedas to Lord Kalki** who is upcoming Avatar of Lord Vishnu during transition times of Kali Yuga and Satya Yuga.

> *suta uvdca tato vastum gurukule yantam kalkim ninksya sah mahendradn
> sthito ramah samaniya asramam prabhuh*
>
> Suta Gosvami said: Thereafter, Lord Kalki went to live at the
> gurukula. Upon seeing Him approach, the greatly powerful Parasuiama,
> who lives at Mount Mahendra, took Him to His asrama.
>
> *praha warn pdthayisyami gurum mam viddhi dharmatah bhrguvamsa
> samutpannam jamadagnyam mahdprabhum*
>
> Lord Parasurama said: My dear child, I will act as Your teacher and so
> You may treat me as Your acarya. I am the son of the greatly powerful
> sage, Jamadagm, and thus I belong to the Bhrgu dynasty.
>
> *veda vedanga tattavajnam dhanurveda visdradam krtva mhksatnyam prthx
> im dattva viprdya daksindm mahendradrau tapastaptum agato'ham
> dvydtmaja warn pathatra пцат vedam yaccanyacchastram uttamam*
>
> I am well-versed in the four Vedas, the literature dealing with
> grammar, and the six branches of the Vedas. I am very expert in the
> art of shooting arrows. Previously, I made the entire earth devoid of
> ksatrnas and then gave the southern portion of the country to the
> brdhmanas Thereafter, I went to Mount Mahendra to perform austerities
> О son of a brahmana, you may stay here and study whatever scriptures
> you like.
>
> *itt tadvaca trprasrutya samprahrsta tanuruhah kalkih puro namaskrtya
> vedadhm tato'bhavat*
>
> Suta GosvamI said: Upon hearing these words of Parasurama, Kalki
> became very pleased and immediately offered His respectful obesiances
> to Him Thereafter, He began to study the Vedas under the direction of
> his spiritual master.

Apart from this, **Lord Parsurama will teach Rukmini Vrata to Ramaa Devi.** Kalki will have two wives Padmavati and Ramaa.

Also, **Parasurama is destined to become Saptarshi for next Manvantara i.e, Saavarni Manvantara.**, which is discussed in [chapter 9 of Matsya purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/23205/25F_Chapter_9.pdf). Savarani Manvantara comes after Vaivasvara Manvantara which is current Manvantara.

> O Royal sage, I am now describing Sävarni Manvantara. **In this
> particular Manvantara, Asvatthämä, garadvän, Kausika, Gälava,
> Satänanda, Kasyapa and Räma (Parasuräma) are the seven Rsis.** Sävarni
> Manu shall have ten sons viz. Dhrti, Variyän, Yavas, Suvarna, Vrsti,
> Carisnu, Idya, Sumati, Vasu and valorous Sukra. These will be his ten
> sons. Similar description has been provided for Raucya and other
> future Manvantaras. At that point of time, Raucya the son of Ruci,
> would be known as Manu. Similarly, Bhautya, the son of Bhüti shall be
> known as Manu. Thereafter, Meru-sävanrni, the son of Brahmä shall be
> known as Manu. Besides them Rta, Rtadhämä and Visvaksena will also be
> known as Manus.