# Is the Parashurama avatara still active?

Tags: parashurama

I don't recall any scripture talking about how he left the earth.  He spans two itihasas, so he obviously lived for a long time.

Comment: The exact answer is already present here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18316

Comment: I am voting to close your question as duplicate as the answer is already present on this site.But you can still modify the wording of the question so that the main enquiry will be different.

Comment: Related [Will Parashurama reappear in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10341/3500)